# React native modular development between teams

Tags: react-native

We have multiple teams working on an app which is built using React Native. Currently, each team has the entire setup of the app and develops and tests it's piece of the code and finally, merges the code to the master where it's onboarded to the release train. This causes issues, for instance, a package upgrade done by one team could cause a regression in another feature using the same package.

Has any team implemented a smarter method of coding with react native? In the web world, we would have a shell UI, with a navigation bar. Each component would have a link on the navigation bar and load inside an iframe when their component was clicked. As such, each team doesn't necessarily needed to have the the entire UI piece setup on their machines. Also their code wouldn't mess around with code from other teams as their code would sit in their repository. They would have separate build and release cycles.

Comment: Do you found an alternative or technique for work at same time with multiple teams?

Comment: My team is having this requirement too.